# Is there a substrate technology explainer available?

Tags: blockchain-frameworks, systemmodule, design

I've seen the developer docs, but what I am looking for is a paper that explains why Substrate is organized in the way that it is. As far as I understand, Substrate builds chains that are EVM-compatible. How does it do that and what design features allow it to do so while still giving the developer flexibility to create modular designs?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Most general questions like this can be answered by reading the official docs at: https://docs.substrate.io/ or various articles available online. I'm voting to close this question as it needs more focus or be more specific.

Comment: @DanielChmielewski Unfortunately such an explainer is either not available or not easily digestible for me (and probably others) through the official docs. As this question is posed to the layman, it would serve to help myself and other people to be directed to the correct portion of a dense, technical documentation set or to good articles detailing how Substrate works. In short, I have searched and cannot find it, so I would like for another person to help

Answer (score 2):

think as you want a blockchain that has fees on transfers, there are many blockchains and you should read all docs and codes to find which parts of that codes are related to manipulating balances so it is extremely hard, but `Polkadot` architecture allows you and pointed to where you can do that. `FRAME` is the power of `Polkadot`. there are some good information about design architecture here https://docs.substrate.io/v3/runtime/frame/

Comment: Simply linking to docs is not a good way to answer a question on Stack Exchange. It's best to quote the key information that answers the question and explain the context. Only then include the link as a reference.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful. I would possibly agree with @DanielChmielewski that highlighting some key information would make this answer even better